# Load pre-trained models in Tensorflow for Java

Tags: java, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to load [pre-trained models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim) in Tensorflow using the Java API.

I notice that over time the format of the saved model files has changed and now there are saved models with file formats `.pb` , `.ckpt` and model directories with `model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 , model.ckpt.index`.

I am following the way to read a model specified in the [LabelImage example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/71c196c1c8c975592a4764784064f72470877a3b/samples/languages/java/label_image/src/main/java/LabelImage.java#L71). But in this example the file format is protobuf `.pb`. I see that the latest saved models are saved in `.ckpt` or `model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 , model.ckpt.index` formats.

I tried to use the [SavedModelBundle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/SavedModelBundle) method with the `export_dir` containing the files - `model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001` and `model.ckpt.index`, but I get this error

```
`2018-07-18 16:54:00.388790: I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:291] SavedModel load for tags { }; Status: fail. Took 95 microseconds.
```

`Exception in thread "main" org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: SavedModel not found in export directory: /path/to/model_dir
    at org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle.load(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle.load(SavedModelBundle.java:39)`

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or let me know as to how I can read the saved models saved in file formats apart from `.pb` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways that you can try to solve your problem:

1. Convert the format of the saved model (checkpoint file) to protobuf file

After restore the saved model to the current session: sess,

```
# Freeze the graph, with output _node_names is the name of the output when construct the model  
# Eg. output_node_names = ["prediction"]
frozen_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants (sess, sess.graph_def, output_node_names)

# Save the frozen graph  
with open (frozen_graph_file, "wb") as f:    
   f.write(frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString()
```

It should convert the former format to the new one.

2. Retrain and save the model to .pb format.